# How to understand " eight million quids’ worth of dental work"

Tags: meaning, short-stories, kevin-barry

The following sentence is taken from Wifey Redux by Kevin Barry:

> "He was seventeen, six two, with blonde, floppy hair, and about eight
>   million quids’ worth of dental work."

How to understand the expression "eight million quids' worth of dental work?" Is the author suggesting that "he" has a mouthful of bad teeth that may take eight million pounds to correct, or "he" has perfect teeth that seems to have been corrected by eight million worth of dental work?

Comment: I think by now enough of your posts have been edited that you should know how to format quoted text: https://literature.stackexchange.com/editing-help#simple-blockquotes

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH FOR THE LINK! I am not a native English speaker and I found some troubles in editting texts but I am learning.

Comment: As a non-native speaker I would take that to mean that his teeth looked like a fortune had been spent on them, i.e. they looked absolutely perfect.

Comment: And 'quid' is slang for a UK pound, by the way.

Comment: @OldBrixtonian True, but in this context (a story set in the Republic of Ireland), "quid" would mean either the former Irish pound or in latter days the euro.

Answer (score 3):

It's hyperbole,  suggesting that a huge sum of money had been spent on cosmetic dentistry.  You can also tell from the reference to his height and the floppy blonde hair that Barry is creating a character from a relatively wealthy background.